# Using NSHost in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, nshost

I'm trying to make a socket server application in Swift for iOS. I found this great example:

```
    let addr = "127.0.0.1"
    let port = 4000

    var host :NSHost = NSHost(address: addr)
    var inp :NSInputStream?
    var out :NSOutputStream?

    NSStream.getStreamsToHost(host, port: port, inputStream: &inp, outputStream: &out)

    let inputStream = inp!
    let outputStream = out!
    inputStream.open()
    outputStream.open()

    var readByte :UInt8 = 0
    while inputStream.hasBytesAvailable {
        inputStream.read(&readByte, maxLength: 1)
    }

    // buffer is a UInt8 array containing bytes of the string "Jonathan Yaniv.".
    outputStream.write("Hello", maxLength: "Hello".length)
```

I tried to run the code in XCode and it said that NSHost didn't exist. I Googled it and I found that NSHost wasn't able for iOS. What can I use instead?

#### Edit

I'm now using Cocoa Async Socket for socket connections. You can find it here [CocoaAsyncScket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket)

Comment: You should probably use CFHostRef from CFNetwork and if you wish to do socket communication, I would reference you the tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server.

Answer (score 2):

Change getStreamsToHost to getStreamsToHostWithName

**Change:**

```
NSStream.getStreamsToHost(host, port: port, inputStream: &inp, outputStream: &out)
```

**to**

```
NSStream.getStreamsToHostWithName(addr, port: port, inputStream: &inp, outputStream: &out)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var server = "127.0.0.1"
var port = 4000
//var host :NSHost = NSHost(address: server)
var inp :NSInputStream?
var out :NSOutputStream?
NSStream.getStreamsToHostWithName(server, port: port, inputStream: &inp, outputStream: &out)
let inputStream = inp!
let outputStream = out!
inputStream.open()
defer {
    inputStream.close()
}
outputStream.open()
defer {
    outputStream.close()
}
// do stuff here
```